# Connect to Azure KeyVault using K8s ConfigMap and Spring Boot

Tags: spring-boot, azure-keyvault, configmap

I have a configmap created in my AKS with these properties

```
 config-application-dev.properties: |
    server.port=5001
    server.compression.enabled=true
    azure.keyvault.uri=<URL>
    azure.keyvault.client-id=<CLIENTID>
    azure.keyvault.client-key=<CLIENTKEY>
```

My Spring boot application read those properties using @PropertySource

```
@PropertySource({ "${propertiesDir}/${envTarget}/config/config-application-${envTarget}.properties" })
public class Application{ 
   ...
}
```

And I want to read the Key using @Value property

```
@Value("${azure-key-vault-secret}")
private String mySecretProperty;
```

But, when SpringBoot starts, It throws this error message ... 
It can't resolve the placeholder ... 
the connection to azure is not working ?

```
    2019-08-21 16:17:26.051  WARN 1 --- [           main] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException:
 Error creating bean with name 'exampleController': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'secret-in-keyvault' in value "${secret-in-keyvault}"
```

Comment: You mus thave secret-in-keyvault somewhere in your code? Can you find that and post the file it is contained in for us please? Thanks.

Comment: Hello!, sorry for the late response. My KeyVault credentials are also in the ConfigMap object. following something like this ...

azure.keyvault.uri=https://wingtiptoyskeyvault.vault.azure.net/
azure.keyvault.client-id=iiiiiiii-iiii-iiii-iiii-iiiiiiiiiiii
azure.keyvault.client-key=pppppppp-pppp-pppp-pppp-pppppppppppp

check this URL - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/java/azure/spring-framework/configure-spring-boot-starter-java-app-with-azure-key-vault?view=azure-java-stable

Comment: Do you have a secret in keyvalut named secret-in-keyvault?

Comment: yes I have some secrets in my vault. At this point I'm not posting the real name of the key, but I think you can get the idea.

Comment: I just followed the document and it worked well. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/java/azure/spring-framework/configure-spring-boot-starter-java-app-with-azure-key-vault?view=azure-java-stable

Comment: It works for me too, but if you put those properties, inside a k8s configMap, it breaks everything !